# Change save button text in admin form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, adminform, magento2.2

I created a form in backend like this:

[image: ex]

I want to  change save button text from 'Save' to 'Insert', here's my code:

> Block\Adminhtml\Tools\Edit.php:

```
namespace Test\UploadFile\Block\Adminhtml\Tools;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;

class Edit extends Container
{

    protected $coreRegistry;

    protected $toolsId=false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'tools_id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_tools';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Lime_UploadFile';

        parent::_construct();

        $toolsId = $this->getToolsId();
        if (!$toolsId) {
            $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
        }
    }


    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        $toolsId = $this->getToolsId();
        if (!$toolsId) {
            return __('New File Item');
        } else {
            return __('Edit File Item');
        }
    }

    public function getToolsId()
    {
        if (!$this->toolsId) {
            $this->toolsId=$this->coreRegistry->registry('current_tools_id');
        }
        return $this->toolsId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `$this->buttonList->update()` to update existing buttons of admin form in `Edit.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/BlockClass/Edit.php

As per your code you can change save button label like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_objectId = 'tools_id';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_tools';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'Lime_UploadFile';

    parent::_construct();

    $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Your Label Here'));

    $toolsId = $this->getToolsId();
    if (!$toolsId) {
        $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
    }
}
```

By this same way, you can change other buttons like **save and continue, reset, back and other admin buttons**

```
$this->buttonList->update('reset', 'label', __('Your Label Here')); //Change Reset Button Label
$this->buttonList->update('back', 'label', __('Your Label Here')); //Change Reset Button Label
$this->buttonList->update('saveandcontinue', 'label', __('Your Label Here')); //Change SaveAndContinue Button Label
$this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Your Label Here')); //Change Delete Button Label
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. You can change your Edit.php file's _construct function as below.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_objectId = 'tools_id';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_tools';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'Lime_UploadFile';

    parent::_construct();
    $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Insert'));
    $toolsId = $this->getToolsId();
    if (!$toolsId) {
        $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
    }
}
```